# As for iPhone Application Development, it is a question

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I am developing iPhone Application.

MyApplicationData.h

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>


@interface MyApplicationData : NSObject {
    NSMutableArray* appData;
}

@property (retain) NSMutableArray* appData;

-(void)loadData;
-(void)addAppDataItemPrice:(NSString*)price itemCategory:(NSString*)category itemDate:(NSDate*)date;
-(void)forDebug;

+(id)instance;

@end
```

MyApplicationData.m

```
#import "MyApplicationData.h"


@implementation MyApplicationData

+ (id)instance
{
    static MyApplicationData* _instance = nil;
    if (!_instance) {
        _instance = [[MyApplicationData alloc] init];
    }
    return _instance;
}

-(void)loadData{
    appData = [NSMutableArray array];
    NSLog(@"%@",appData);
}

-(void)forDebug{
}

-(void)addAppDataItemPrice:(NSString*)price itemCategory:(NSString*)category itemDate:(NSDate*)date{
    NSLog(@"%@", appData);
    [appData addObject:@"1"];
    NSLog(@"%@", appData);
}

@end
```

another class

```
[[MyApplicationData instance] loadData];
```

one another class

```
[[MyApplicationData instance] addAppDataItemPrice:price itemCategory:category itemDate:date];
```

log

```
[Session started at 2009-11-03 21:04:41 +0900.]
2009-11-03 21:04:44.742 XXX[24002:207] (
)
2009-11-03 21:04:46.612 XXX[24002:207] (null)
```

It is not executed. What is the cause?

Comment: Just to be sure, I would log the name of the method being called and the value of instance, e.g.: `NSLog(@"loadData: %@: %@", instance, appData);`

Answer (score 1):

I think this line might be the cause:

```
appData = [NSMutableArray array];
```

try this instead:

```
appData = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init]
```

You'll want to make sure you release it as well when your MyApplicationData instance is destroyed (not critical in this case since it's a singleton, but still good practice)

Answer (score 1):

It looks like your array is getting autoreleased after the method:

```
[[MyApplicationData instance] loadData];
```

I think it should be a member of the class, you can use the property syntax to help.

Set it up in the header file as:

```
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSMutableArray *appdata;
```

Then in the implementation:

```
@synthesize appdata;
```

Assign it as follows:

```
-(void)loadData{
    self.appData = [NSMutableArray array];
}
```

Don't forget to release it in your `dealloc` method

When you set it in your code you can call it like the following:

```
[self.appData addObject:@"1"];
```

Comment: For completeness sake, this is the line he should use: `self.appData = [NSMutableArray array];`